# Solving and interpreting $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+x^2y$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R} $.

Tags: calculus, functions, intuition, functional-equations

The question reads,
 Find all differentiable functions $f$ such that $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+x^2y$$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R} $. The function $f$ also satisfies $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac {f(x)}x = 0$$

To solve the problem I wrote the expression for $\frac{df}{dx}$ using first principle and found that $\frac{df}{dx} = x^2.$(Due to the given conditions.)

Using this and calculating $f(0)$ as zero I got the implication that $f(x)$ must be $\frac{x^3}{3}.$

But,
Clearly the calculated $f(x)$ does not satisfy the required condition for the problem. Thinking about where I had committed the mistake, I realized that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+x^2y$ cannot be true for all real $x,y$.

So how is it that these operations that implied $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}$ went wrong?

And why is it that while doing these operations I could not 'see' that the conditions cannot be satisfied for all real $x$?

EDIT:Reading the comments, I want to make the clarification that I realise the fact that there can not be any $ f(x) $ that satisfies these conditions using a different method. However I fail to understand why the method elaborated in the question does not reflect this fact to me??

Comment: The defining equation is... unusual.  By symmetry you would also have $f(x+y)=f(y+x)=f(x)+f(y)+y^2x$ from which you could deduce that $x^2y=y^2x$ for all $x,y$, no?

Comment: Exactly! Which is exacly why I am facing problem in this question

Comment: I don't see any problem.  The defining equation is impossible, so there is no such function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem conditions are implicitly self-contradictory. If we accept them and shall follow them then we can rigorously prove a lot of claims about the function $f$ and we can believe that everything is OK, until we obtain an explicit contradiction.

I [quote](http://ceadserv1.nku.edu/longa//classes/mat385_resources/docs/russellpope.html) famous Bertrand Russell’s illustration.

> The story goes that Bertrand Russell, in a lecture on logic, mentioned that in the sense of material implication, a false proposition implies any proposition.
> A student raised his hand and said "In that case, given that $1 = 0$, prove that you are the Pope."
> Russell immediately replied, "Add $1$ to both sides of the equation: then we have $2 = 1$. The set containing just me and the Pope has 2 members. But $2 = 1$, so it has only $1$ member; therefore, I am the Pope."

Also we can easily construct a formal logical argument showing that a contradiction implies any proposition.

Comment: This is what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: @AlexRavsky "*The story goes that Bertrand Russell*" There does not seem to be any credible source for this "story". Many people source the story to the same Internet page, which itself does not provide any source. Maybe it is time to stop pretending we know Russell is the source?

Answer (score 6):

There cannot be any function satisfying this equation for the simple reason that $f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)$ does not change if you interchange $x$ and $y$. So if such a function exists we must have $x^{2}y=y^{2}x$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$ which is absurd.

Now as to what went wrong in your approach: From $x^{2} =-1$ you can deduce that $x^{4}= 1$ but $x^{4} =1$ is not the final answer. In fact there is no real number  $x$ such that $x^{2} =-1$. The simple answer to your question is converse of result is not always true. If you got $f(x)=\frac {x^{3}} 3$ from the given equation it doesn't mean that there is a solution. You should always go back to the original equation and check if the function you obtained is indeed a solution. If it is not then you have not arrived at any contradiction because converse of result is not always true.

Comment: @Aditya Sharma I have added some explanation to clear your confusion. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful explanation. That really opened my eyes

Answer (score -2):

First notice by letting $x=y=0$ we get $f(0)=0$. Further we have $$f(x+y)-f(x) = f(y) +x^2y$$ now if $y\ne 0$ we have $$\lim _{y\to 0} {f(x+y)-f(x)\over y} = \lim _{y\to 0} \big({f(y)\over y} +x^2\big)$$

so we have $f'(x) =x^2$ and thus, for some real $c$ we have $$f(x) ={x^3\over 3}+c$$
Since $f(0)=0$ we get $c=0$. As always we have to chek it buy pluging it in starting equation:
$${(x+y)^3\over 3} = {x^3\over 3}+{y^3\over 3} +x^2y\implies y^2x=0$$
for all $x$ and $y$ which is clearly nosene.

Answer (score -2):

Your expression is not a representation of a function on as wide domain as $\mathbb{R}$, but it does not mean that it is totally meaningless.

Replace $y=x$ and you have got

$$f(2x)=2f(x)+x^3$$

This function has a solution

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{6}(x^2+c)$$

If you replace this general solution you will get

$$ xy(x-y)=0 $$

which gives the domains 1. $x=0, y \in \mathbb{R}$, 2. $y=0, x \in \mathbb{R}$, 3. $y = x$.

The domains $1.$ and $2.$ are covered with any function as you get no condition except $f(x)=f(x)$.

For third one the solution is as above:

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{6}(x^2+c)$$

Therefore it does not exist a function for all independent $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, only for  $x,y(x) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Your second condition requires $c=0$ for third domain, and just any function that satisfies the limit for domains $1.$ and $2.$

Comment: You know too much about math to give this answer -1.